# TypeError: _fakeTimers(...).JestFakeTimers is not a constructor

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, docker-compose, jestjs

I have a Node js server which has some tests running with `jest`. The result of the `npm test` ON LOCAL MACHINE is absolutely fine.

This Node js server runs inside a docker container. Here is the `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM node:12.14.1-alpine

RUN mkdir /usr/app

WORKDIR /usr/app

COPY . /usr/app
RUN apk update && apk upgrade && apk add --no-cache git
RUN npm install -g jest
RUN npm i
RUN npm test
CMD npm start
```

When we build the docker image, it breaks at `RUN npm test` stage with the following error:

```
FAIL src/test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: _fakeTimers(...).JestFakeTimers is not a constructor

      at new JSDOMEnvironment (node_modules/jest-environment-jsdom/build/index.js:149:23)
```

I can't figure out why this is happening.

Any help will be appreciated.

Cross posting to [Github](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/10441)

Comment: I don't know much about Docker, but perhaps you can run `npm install` again? That's what solved my `TypeError: _fakeTimers(...).JestFakeTimers is not a constructor` issue.